# call php function from python

Tags: php, python, function, subprocess

My PHP code:

```
function start($height, $width) {
    # do stuff
    return $image;
}
```

Here my Python code:

```
import subprocess
def php(script_path):
        p = subprocess.Popen(['php', script_path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        result = p.communicate()[0]
            return result

    page_html = "test entry"
    output = php("file.php") 
    print page_html + output

    imageUrl = start(h,w)
```

In Python I want to use that PHP start function. I don't know how to access start function from Python. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how I do it. It works like a charm.

```
# shell execute PHP
def php(code):
  # open process
  p = Popen(['php'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
  
  # read output
  o = p.communicate(code)[0]
  
  # kill process
  try:
    os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
  except:
    pass
  
  # return
  return o
```

To execute a particular file do this:

```
width = 100
height = 100

code = """<?php

  include('/path/to/file.php');
  echo start(""" + width + """, """ + height + """);

?>
"""
res = php(code)
```

Note that for Python3 you need `res = php(code.encode())`, see the answer below

Comment: How do i access start function from python script?

Comment: I updated my code. You should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: I got error "Could not open input file:". Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Did you edit the code I gave you to reflect the path to where your file is located? I am not here to do everything for you. Read the code until you  understand it and then implement it.

Comment: tntu, I want to pass variable echo start(100, 100);
like echo start(h,w); Is that possible?

Comment: @ishita Yes you can. Do the width and height come from Python?

Comment: I tried to pass width and height but nothing come out. code: echo start(h,w); Yes width and height came from python. So can you please guide me how to pass python variable? Thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: I suggest you study a bit more Python and PHP in order to better understand how they work. This should help you figure out things by yourself much easier. Most people here would not have bothered as much as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Small update to previous response:

For python3 code string should be encoded to bytes-like object

```
php(code.encode())
```