# Using PHP & Tornado

Tags: php, python, nginx, tornado

I'm using Tornado as my webserver to host one of it's chat examples. I added a little php to it's example index.html so that it is now index.php and when I ran the website I found that the php didn't render, instead the php just showed itself in the html of the webpage when I clicked 'view source'.

To my dismay I found that PHP and Tornado which is essentially Python could not work together. Is there any way whatsoever that I can bypass this? I've heard about using engines like nginx to host my php code  and that somehow it would solve the problem?

Any suggestions?

**P.S.** I understand that I haven't shown any code and I've upset some users by not showing any code but I jut didn't think it necessary but just in case:

```
<?php
 echo "My name is Pappi";
?>
```

Comment: So essentially what you're trying to do is run index.php but the php isn't working because Tornado doesn't render it. Assuming you simply edited a tornado template, try making a page from scratch and see if the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can be executed from the shell via `php script_name.php` using PHP CLI (Command Line Interface).  It is also possible to call system commands from python and read their output using the subprocess module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.  You can thus execute php commands from the shell and read the result into your python program.  See this post for an example: [call php function from python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214595/call-php-function-from-python).

Once you get the results of the executed php into python, it can then be passed into your template.