# How to add string var inside php code in python

Tags: python, php, django

I saw a [php code](https://paiza.io/projects/nfypk-PIngljyIyXLJ-_nw) to decrypt an encrypted `AES-256-CBC` string in PHP. But I'm using python, so I looked for a way to add a PHP script inside python.

This is how I did it as I saw from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20214666/12415287):

```
def decrypt(encrypted_data, password):
code = """<?php
  function decryptionM($data, $key) {
    $secretkey = str_pad($key, 32, '*'); 
    echo('secretkey: ');
    echo($secretkey);
    echo("\n");
    
    $iv_with_ciphertext = base64_decode(str_replace('plusencr', '+', $data));
    echo('iv_with_ciphertext: ');
    echo($iv_with_ciphertext);
    echo("\n");
    
    $iv_length = openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC');
    echo('iv_length: ');
    echo($iv_length);
    echo("\n");
    $iv = substr($iv_with_ciphertext, 0, $iv_length);
    echo('iv: ');
    echo($iv);
    echo("\n");
    $ciphertext = substr($iv_with_ciphertext, $iv_length);
    echo('ciphertext: ');
    echo($ciphertext);
    echo("\n");
    $text = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'aes-256-cbc', $secretkey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    echo('text: ');
    echo($text);
    echo("\n");
    $asArr = explode(',', $text);
    echo('asArr: ');
    echo($asArr);
    echo("\n");
    foreach ($asArr as $val) { 
        $tmp = explode('=', $val);
        echo('tmp: ');
        echo($tmp[0]);
        echo("\n");
        $finalArray[trim($tmp[0])] = str_replace('+', '', $tmp[1 ]); 
    }
    echo('finalArray: ');
    echo($finalArray);
    echo("\n");
    return $finalArray; 
}

  echo decryptionM(""" + encrypted_data + """, """ + password + """);

?>
"""
res = php(code.encode())

return res
```

But the line `echo decryptionM(""" + encrypted_data + """, """ + password + """);` is outputting an error:

```
[2022-03-24 02:06:50,202: WARNING/MainProcess] b"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in Standard input code on line 55\n\nParse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')' in Standard input code on line 55\n"
```

which I figured is caused by not having quotes surrounding the parameters which are strings when the `echo decryptionM(""" + encrypted_data + """, """ + password + """);` is transformed to PHP code.

`decryptionM(data, key);` should be `decryptionM('data', 'key');`

How do I do this in python or PHP?

Comment: This is insane. Why not either (a) just run the PHP code in PHP, or (b) port it to Python?

Comment: @Chris This is the code in the [API](https://support.northcapital.com/knowledge/encrypt-webhook-events) I'm using. I'm also using Django so this seems like the fastest way to do it.

Comment: I'll quote from that page, with some extra emphasis: "Here is a code snippet to _assist with implementation_". Not to copy wholesale into a string in another programming language. If you're using Django forget about option (a) and go with option (b). Python can definitely do [Base64](https://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) and [AES](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/).

Comment: @Chris the pycrypto install was not working before, and it's repo is now archived and unmaintained.

Comment: That was just an example. Maybe not the best one, but its homepage lists alternatives: https://cryptography.io/, https://www.pycryptodome.org/. I promise you, spending 5 minutes to find a library and a bit of time to port this code is worth doing over cramming PHP code into Python.